# how to select with two date condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date '$user_input_date' that i receive it from user and
i have a query inside other query in select clause and i want to select total hours in this sub query with two condition like bellow

```
$sql="SELECT teacher.teacher_id,name,lname,father_name,salary_per_hour,monthly_salary,"
            . "(select ($user_month - month(salary_start_date)) from teacher where teacher_id=$id) as deff_month ,"
            . "(select ADDDATE(salary_start_date, interval deff_month month) from teacher where teacher_id=$id) as start_interval, "
            . "(select ADDDATE(start_interval, interval 1 month)) as end_interval ,"
            . " (select DATE_SUB(start_interval, interval 1 month)) as reverse_end_interval,"
            . "(**select sum(hours) from teacher_hours_late where date>= start_interval AND date<end_interval OR date>=start_interval AND date<reverse_end_interval and teacher_id=$id ) as total_late**"
            . " from teacher where teacher.branch_id=$branch_id and teacher.teacher_id=$id"
```

my object is to achive total hours in date interval by the date that i receive from user like that if start_interval>$user_input_date then i want to select interval between **start_interval and end_interval** otherwise select interval between **start_interval and reverce_end_interval** in where clause of below query my candition in where clause is wrong because i have no idea please help me dears                     `select sum(hours) from teacher_hours_late where date>= start_interval AND date<end_interval OR date>=start_interval AND date<reverse_end_interval and teacher_id=$id ) as total_late`

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis are required to isolated the between date conditionals.

**Before**

```
where date>= start_interval AND date<end_interval OR date>=start_interval AND date<reverse_end_interval
```

**After**

```
where (date>= start_interval AND date<end_interval) OR (date>=start_interval AND date<reverse_end_interval)
```

Comment: Parenthesis is not my problem dear WorkSmarter i have no idea how to make a condition by the $user_input date if user date is bigger than start interval then i want to sum hours between  date>start_interval AND date<end_interval otherwise sum hours between date>=start_interval AND date<reverse_end_interval

Comment: Without the use of parenthesis the date conditionals will not function as expected. Instead of comparing two date conditionals, a total of 3 conditions would be evaluated e.g. date>= start_interval AND date<end_interval OR date>=start_interval.

Comment: you are correct dear i have that problem on Parenthesis i fix it but i want to use $user_input_date to check  if $user_input_date is bigger than start_interval then i want to sum hours between date>start_interval AND date<end_interval otherwise sum hours between date>=start_interval AND date<reverse_end_interval   how to check $user_input_date and Make a decision